# Allow only english characters and nr in html input field. This is valid and for copy/paste

Tags: javascript, html, input

I want to allow only english characters and numbers in html input field (A-Z, a-z, 0-9 are allowed). I don't want that someone to insert special characters with copy/paste.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1995521/jquery-js-allow-only-numbers-letters-in-a-textfield

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to allow only numeric (0-9) in HTML  inputbox using jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/995183/how-to-allow-only-numeric-0-9-in-html-inputbox-using-jquery)

Answer (score 3):

If you are using new browser you can use `pattern` attribute like

```
<input type="text" pattern="[A-Za-z0-9]" required/>
```

or you can use js like

```
$("#id").keypress(function(event){
    var ew = event.which;
    if(48 <= ew && ew <= 57)
        return true;
    if(65 <= ew && ew <= 90)
        return true;
    if(97 <= ew && ew <= 122)
        return true;
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Check this `pattern="^[\x20-\x7F]+$`" 
At me this it work:D

```
<input type="text" pattern="^[\x20-\x7F]+$" >
```

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript, create a conditional checking for ASCII values. A way to do this is 
    `var character` will represent one character of the array of characters entered into the input field.

`character.charCodeAt(0);` will turn it into an ASCII value. Then just use < than and > than symbols to check if the ASCII values are in range of letters and numbers.