# I can't find the simplest of textarea validation

Tags: jquery, html, validation

I want just a simplest textarea with validation rule by `onkeypress` in jQuery but NOT in HTML5, bootstrap, or angularJS. I can't find it anywhere. For example it fills by these:

Corrects: `spaces, letter, number, many words,-,+,_,/,.`

Incorrects: `',",!,@,#,$,%,^,%,*,space in front and last`

I can do it by angularJS but not in JQuery. I just want it in jQuery pattern or another way in jQuery. If the content of textarea is not in the correct way in its pattern, the submit button hiding or disabled then. Thanks for your help.

I've been looking for references among them like these (they can be filled by `'` single quote):

1. http://www.jeasyui.com/tutorial/form/form3.php
2. http://trevordavis.net/play/jQuery-Simple-Validate/
3. http://www.innovativephp.com/applications/demos/jquery_form_validation_examples/textarea_validation
4. http://jsfiddle.net/ZAaPu/
5. https://www.daniweb.com/programming/web-development/threads/449610/textarea-validation-problem-jquery

Comment: Got any code for us?

Comment: why do you give me a downvote? i've been looking for this way almost 6 hours but i couldn't find it the best for me yet.

Comment: Do you want to validate, or do you want to prevent them from being added?

Comment: prevent is better i think @epascarello

Comment: Something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1995521/jquery-js-allow-only-numbers-letters-in-a-textfield

Comment: still doesn't worked epascarello. they still can be filled by ' (single quote). I want if i type singe quote, then it will disappear immediately like we press a backspace on keyboard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#input').keyup(function() {
     if(!$(this).val().match(/^(?!\s)([a-zA-Z0-9 _.)?&]){1,}$/g)) {
           $('#button').prop('disabled', true);
        }else{
           $('#button').prop('disabled', false);
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="input" />
<input id="button" type="button" value="submit" />
```

Comment: It works in here Zorken17 and i tried in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/junaserbaserbi/6feuLyvq/1/) and it works also, but if i copy into my php file, it doesn't worked, why?

Comment: @Junaserbaserbi  you inserted the jquery CDN in your code?

Comment: Give me your php/html code, so I can see what's wrong.

Comment: [imgur](http://i.imgur.com/F6MEcOQ.jpg), it's wierd Zorken, i'm really confused, whereas I just copied your code.

Comment: @Junaserbaserbi you need to insert jQuery to your project for it to work. And if you have not linked jQuer it won't work.

Comment: Please insert your php/html code for us to help you further.

Comment: you mean insert this: <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> ?

Comment: I can see it, but not sitting on a computer so can't test I fully. I will do that as son as I get to one.

Comment: I already put that thing from the beginning (i just copying from you), you can see  fbmeledak.com/ztest1.php right? but it doen't worked, why?

Comment: I don't know, where have you put the jquery CDN, in the head of your html page? You maybe need to put the code in a $(document).ready() scope.

Comment: i put into [tophead](http://fbmeledak.com/ztest1.php), [bottomhead](http://fbmeledak.com/ztest2.php), [topbody](http://fbmeledak.com/ztest3.php), [bottombody](http://fbmeledak.com/ztest4.php), it's not work either

Comment: Let me come back to you when I am sitting at a computer so I can debug your code.

Comment: you can right click and **view page source** to see the result, ok Zorken, i'm waiting for you. thank you.

Comment: I know, but I am sitting on a mobile device.

Comment: ok anytime Zorken. I feel like an headache now, this is 11.30pm in Indonesia right now.

Comment: Ok, so I see that you are not so familiar with javascript. If you want to have the code in the header it must be surrounded by $ ( document) .ready ( ) that I wrote before, or else you can insert it after your html elements. Javascript can not be executed before the elements are loaded. I changed my code here above, so take it and copy in the same way it will work.

Comment: OK, it's worked finally. You alright Zorken, I'm newbie in Jquery. Thanks for your help Zorken. +9 for you.

Comment: Zorken, please help me again in [this]( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33622363/disabled-a-submit-button-is-not-working-after-i-press-a-single-quotes), it is still your code yesterday.

Comment: Zorken, please help me again in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33669459/confusing-about-this-cookies-in-redirecting-system), because no body wants to answer me Zorken.